# Render <b> Instead of <strong> for Bold Text in Markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll to generate a static site and one thing that I noticed is that using the [standard Markdown syntax for emphasis](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#emphasis), ** or __ renders `<strong>` instead of `<b>`, and * or _ renders `<em>` instead of `<i>`.

Is there a way to render `<b>` and `<i>` instead of `<strong>` and `<em>`?

Comment: Why?  `<strong/>` and `<em/>` *are* the correct tags.  (IIRC, `<b/>` and `<i/>` are preserved only for backwards compatibility.)

Comment: Not in every situation. Those are semantic, but there are instances where you don't need (or want) to provide the extra emphasis, e.g., a book/movie title, `<i>Charlie and the Chocolate Factory</i>`. However, Jekyll will always render `<em>`.

Comment: ...then either don't use `*Charlie...*`, or change the CSS style to match your needs.

Comment: Which Markdown implementation are you using (Jekyll supports many)? Some allow customization and others don't. In any event, you would probably need an implementation which provides for plugins/extensions to alter the behavior.

Comment: Using Kramdown.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps depending upon your markdown, but just use it directly like this:

`this is <b>something style bolded</b> only`

= this is **something style bolded** only

and:

`this is <i>something style italicised</i> only`

= this is *something style italicised* only

Off topic: There would be very limited times when `<strong>` and `<em>` are not the better choice - if you're emphasising it, you're emphasising it.